# How can I find out the activation details from the internal KMS server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, kms

I have any internal KMS server running on Server2012R2 and We are using it to activate Office internally, Is there a way that I can output a list of details of the activation like UserName, ComputerName, Activation date/time and periad etc.

So far all I can see from the cli is the total number of the activations and few other info, I would like to have a list of users who was activated by this KMS server

Possible?

Comment: Microsoft KMS does not store this information. The KMS exists only to perform the activation that would normally be performed by the client directly to Microsoft, by sending the uniquely identifying information for each client to Microsoft and returning the activation back to the client. It isn't used as a repository for licensing or consumption or auditing. For *future* activations, it is possible to use the KMS Windows event log to capture this information, and of course clients under your scope of management should be able to provide this using your configuration management solution.